# Creating Default New Channels in GetStream.io Website

Tags: node.js, channel, getstream-io, getstream-chat

Goal: When a new user signs up I want several team chats to generate with set users I define and the newly created user.

Result: No new channel is generated in any capacity including on the getstream.io website.

Note: I am able to manually create a channel in the website.

---

I AM NEW TO CODING AND WEB DEVELOPMENT, ANY ADVICE AND ASSISTANCE IS GREATLY APPRECIATED!!!

I have my website set up with a client and server to handle the front end and backend. I created a "DefaultChannel" file that I then have being ran through my "Auth" file with code that should trigger an error if the code is not executed properly. I have gotten 0 errors referencing the "DefaultChannel" call out I have used in my Auth and have no idea where my code is going wrong.

Below is the code I have for this setup
GitHub: https://github.com/LookitszTral/DefaultChannelSetup.git

I followed the following YouTube video to create a getstream.io messaging website: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MJzbJQLGehs&t=8663s&ab_channel=JavaScriptMastery

I have used ChatGPT for a lot of this so I am sure plenty is done in not the most efficient way either so any advice there would be greatly appreciated as as well!

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.